# Changing existing registry value at install with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry, installation

I feel like I've searched high and low for this but I seem to be hitting hurdle after hurdle.

I have a written a fairly simple program for managing Outlook email signatures. To ensure that I can catch every email event (new, reply, forwarded) I need to change a registry value that ensures that the email pops out of the Outlook window automatically. I know the registry path and if I change the value manually everything works OK. I have written 2 simple executables to be run at the Install phase of my Windows Installer Setup project which when run standalone outside of the Windows Installer work fine but found when embedded into the Windows Installer they weren't running correctly. With the help of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428615/installer-custom-action-cant-read-all-registry-values) it turns out that Windows Installer custom actions are run as the SYSTEM account and not as the currently logged in user. I implemented the  `PostBuildEvent` script process mentioned in the post and I can now change the registry value during when running the setup.

The problem I have now is that I am unable to find something similar for the custom actions during the Uninstall phase as I want to ensure that the value is reset to the original value.

**Standalone working code**

This code works when run as a standalone executable and when run in the conditions described in the linked post using the `PostBuildEvent` the result is produced but I require this at the **Uninstall** phase rather than the **Install** phase.

```
    Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary

    Class Module1

    Shared Sub Main()
         Dim objShell As WshShell = New WshShell
         Dim RegLocate As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Message\DisableReadingPaneCompose"
         objShell.RegWrite(RegLocate, "0", "REG_DWORD")
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: What code did you try on uninstall

Comment: Hi @Mederic, I haven't tried any yet. I have a working executable that runs but when running this during the custom actions phase of the uninstaller the registry value isn't changed. The fix for this during the installation phase were the actions from the post I cited but I have been unable to find any equivalent for the uninstall phase. I have updated the question with the standalone working code

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your question so it's well formated just like explained in [ask]

Comment: Hi @Mederic, I've updated the above post which I think conforms to the rules. If not can you let me know what I've missed. Thanks in advance.